I've burninated a few tags, sorry for the mess on the frontpage
I've manually burninated the following tags:

control: Multiple topics, so I replaced it with governance, ownership, coin-control 
speed: Multiple topics, replaced with hashrate, transaction-capacity, block-interval
support: Replaced with adoption, specific service name, or just removed.

And merged

export -> private-key-export
restore -> wallet-recovery
2fa -> two-factor-authentication

